# jQuery keyup function stops working when trying to insert into a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, mysqli

This is  a weird problem and I'm not sure how to approach it.

At the moment I'm trying to have the user enter an ingredient - a list of ingredients appears as you type with buttons next to them to add them which should insert them into  SQL database.

The list population ceases to function when I uncomment

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

In the .click function of the add button.
Which is strange because it's like the .keyup function just stops working.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Cocktails</title>
    <script src="http://assets.absolutdrinks.com/api/addb-0.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>

        <form>
          <input type="text" name="ingredientinput" id="ingredientinput"><br>
        </form> 
        <div id="ingredientlist">

        </div>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                //ajax call to query cokctail DB 
                //handleData is callback function that handles result
                function get_ingredients(query,handleData){
                    var apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                    var rooturl = "http://addb.absolutdrinks.com/";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: rooturl + "/quickSearch/ingredients/" + query + "/",  
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        data: {apiKey:apikey},
                        success: function(data) {

                                handleData(data);
                            },
                        error: function(){
                            //error
                        }
                    });
                }





                //when text is entered - quicksearch the database
                $("#ingredientinput").keyup(function(){
                    query = $(this).val();                  //value of textbox
                    divlist = "";                           //list of ingredients
                    objectlist = {};
                    if (query.length > 0){
                        //set loading image on keypress
                        $("#ingredientlist").html("<img src='images/spinner.gif' alt='loading' height='24' width='24'>");

                        //pass query to ajax call and handle result
                        get_ingredients(query,function(data){
                            console.log(data);

                            //build list of ingredients
                            $.each(data["result"], function(key, value){

                                divlist += "<div id='" + value["id"] + "'>" + value["name"] + "<button class='addbutton' type='button' id = '"+value["id"]+"'>+</button></div>";                            
                                objectlist[value["id"]] = value;


                                //clicking button dumps object to file?
                            });

                            $("#ingredientlist").html(divlist);         //populate div ingredientlist with results
                            divlist = "";                               //clear html builder
                        });
                        console.log("input query:" + query);

                    }
                    else{
                        $("#ingredientlist").html("");                  //if no input clear list
                    }
                });

                $("#ingredientlist").on('click','button.addbutton',function(){
                    $("#ingredientlist").on('click','button.addbutton',function(){

                    current = objectlist[this.id];
                    sqlquery = current["description"] + "," + current["id"] + "," + current["isAlcoholid"] + "," + current["isBaseSpirit"] + "," + current["isCarbonated"] + "," + current["isJuice"] + "," + current["languageBranch"] + "," + current["name"] + "," + current["type"];
                    console.log(sqlquery);
                    <?php



                        $servername = "localhost";
                        $username = "root";
                        $password = "**";
                        $dbname = "ingredients";


                        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO cocktails (description, id, isAlcoholic, isBaseSpirit, isCarbonated, isJuice, languageBranch, name, type)
                        VALUES ('test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test','test',)";

                        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                            echo "New record created successfully";
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                        }

                        mysqli_close($conn);

                        ?>





                });
                });

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't post api key

Comment: @A.Wolff It's not terribly bad, because it's a javascript side API, which is publically available for anyone viewing the source of his website.

Comment: @FrankerZ Ya, you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just embed a save query from within javascript like you are doing. This is a server side function that needs to happen, and return a result (Almost like you're doing with your `get_ingredients` function.)

My suggestion, is create a `save_ingredients` function that works through ajax to pass the information (In this case, the ingredient to save) to the server.

in `saveingredients.php`:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "**";
$dbname = "ingredients";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$description = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'description', $_GET['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$isAlcoholic = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'isAlcoholic', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
$isBaseSpirit = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'isBaseSpirit', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
$isCarbonated = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'isCarbonated', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
$isJuice = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'isJuice', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
$languageBranch = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'languageBranch', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$type = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

$sql = "INSERT INTO cocktails (description, id, isAlcoholic, isBaseSpirit, isCarbonated, isJuice, languageBranch, name, type)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ( $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) )
{
    $stmt->bind_param('sdsssssss', $description, $id, $isAlcoholic, $isBaseSpirit, $isJuice, $languageBranch, $name, $type);

    if ($stmt->execute($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo json_encode('error' => false);
    } else {
        echo json_encode('error' => 'MySQL Error: ' . $conn->error);
    }
}


$conn->close($conn);

?>
```

A sample AJAX function:

```
function saveingredients(current) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveingredients.php',
        data: {
            description: current["description"],
            id: current["id"],
            isAlcoholid: current["isAlcoholid"],
            isBaseSpirit: current["isBaseSpirit"],
            isCarbonated: current["isCarbonated"],
            isJuice: current["isJuice"],
            languageBranch: current["languageBranch"],
            name: current["name"],
            type: current["type"]
        },
        success: function(res) {
            if ( res.error )
            {
                console.log(res.error);
            }
            else
            {
                //Do something here because it inserted correctly.
            }
        },
        failure: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So have a `save_ingredients(sqlquery)` in the onclick then in that function use ajax to pass the object to a php file & add it to the DB?

Comment: @Supertod, I think you need to go back and read PHP and Javascript 101. PHP is a server side scripting language, that processes a request and returns the result. Javascript is a clientside language which runs from the clients computer. Any interaction between the two needs to be handled through a proper request sent to the server (Ie. AJAX or submitting a form). You can't just dump PHP in the middle of javascript, because at that point, you've echoed out a giant string of javascript (To be run by the browser), and **that's it**. I recommend reading a tutorial on how to get started with ajax.

Comment: I've updated my answer @Supertod, and I've given you an example on how you could potentially do this. I hope this helps you. Please note, I've taken some assumptions not knowing how the data is stored (ie. id is int, is.. are all bools, etc...). You may need to change things to correspond with your data.